# error in calling a function that updates entry in a database

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the code where the error occurs:

```
     '$' def update(id, title, author, year, isbn):
       conn=sqlite3.connect("books.db")
       cur=conn.cursor()

       cur.execute("UPDATE book SET title=?, author=?, year=?, isbn=? WHERE 
       id=?",(title,author, year, isbnو id))

       conn.commit()
       conn.close() '$'
```

i have tried reordering the tuples where id goes first now the error no longer exists but the function is not working in that case

Comment: Hi, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: 1. I'm assuming '$' is a code limiters, right? 
If is the case, please, don't do this! 

2. Could you please post some error message?. 
Without error message is difficult to help!

3. There is a strange character in this snippet "title,author, year, isbnو id" betwwen isbn and id. I have no idea what is it...

Comment: What is the character following `isbn` in the `execute` call? It looks like a quirky (Arabic?) comma.